# restoring scroll position in Flex Web Page

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

This is a fairly crucial but overlooked functionality I guess in a web page - on a standard (non flex) web page, navigate away from the page and return to it via the back or forward button and it restores the scroll position you were at on the page previously.  This is a crucial function and it would get very annoying if it wasn't there - having a page automatically go back to the very top each time when you were previously scrolled way down on a long text site.  I guess the browser itself must be managing this,as I was surprised to find that even deleting cookies, the cache and basically everything will not get rid of that saved scroll position.

So the problem is doing that on a flex web page - what is the correct way to do it.  I have been using SHaredObject.getLocal,  but was dumbfounded to discover that once a local shared object is created , it will NEVER be deleted, there is nothing a user can do in the browser to delete them (deleting cookies, etc has no effect.)  So I had like 100 different sharedobjects in a Macromedia subdirectory storing nothing but scroll positions.  Even with standard web pages you can delete browsing history, but with SharedObject they're there for good unless you actually just delve into that file subdirectory and delete them manually (which of course a user would never do.) So a subquestion would be, is it really true that there is no way to delete SharedObjects from the browser.  FLex even calls SharedObjects "Flash cookies" in their docs,  but with real cookies the user can delete them.

Comment: Just discovered you can create *actual* cookies from Flex using Javascript.  THis seems preferable, as they can actually be deleted, and to clutter up a user's machine with 100's of Flex SharedObjects storing nothing but trivial session data, that can NEVER be deleted seems absurd.

Comment: Users can delete cookies using the Flash Settings Manager.  http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html I know that doesn't answer your question, but I thought it was worth noting.  (Most of my users wouldn't know how to clear browser cookies).

Comment: All I see in Settings Manager is an option for how much storage the website can store locally . Do you mean just setting it to 0? That's not the same as an option to just delete all existing "Flash cookies" (local SharedObjects). I assume most users know how to just delete Standard cookies from their browser. The question is, why know built in Flash capability to handle local data via the standard browser mechanism - browser cookies. Anyway, looks like there are 3rd party libraries for flex to do this.

Comment: I see now the link you provided is the actual settings manager. (There is a local settings manager accessible via right click in a Flex web page with fewer options.)

Comment: @Mark. There are a number of reasons why Shared Objects are useful. For one, they'll let you store AS objects (as opposed to strings; you can serialize objects to strings, true, but with a SO you don't even have to care about this). Also, creating real cookies involves calling JS, which is generally but not always allowed. I'd say, if you really need a cookie, go with it. And though it's true that there's no UI for deleting Shared Objects, you could definitely delete them (they're just files on you HD).

Comment: @Mark. By the way, you assume most users know how to delete cookies from the browser. In my experience, most users don't have a clue what cookies are or even that they exist (and they don't care in the sligthest about this, which, if you ask me, is fairly reasonable and understandable).

Comment: Juan - My problem with SharedObjects is that is seems ridiculous for there to be an unending accumulation of them with no standard well-known way of deleting them.  I was creating a shared object on a per URL basis, and as I mentioned I had 100's of SharedObject storing nothing but trivial session data.  But anyway, I found a solution to my problem for what its worth - a circular buffer stored in a local SharedObject, where after a max number of URL info objects is reached the oldest one is deleted before adding a new one.  So I'll provide the code in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to have just one SharedObject for all URL's generated, and this SHaredObject holds an object operating as a circular buffer.  This object has properties indexed by URL, with each property pointing to the session info for that URL (e.g. scroll position, etc.).  Haven't tested the following yet, but this is what I've got.  If there is already a built in way in Flex to do a circular buffer in a local SharedObject I haven't found it.

```
function createSessionInfo(url:String,info:Object):void {  

  var so_obj:SharedObject = null;
  try { 
    so_obj = SharedObject.getLocal("Session_Info","/");
  } catch (e:*) {}          
  if (!so_obj) return;

  if (so_obj.data.session == undefined)
    so_obj.data.session = new Object();

  var session:Object = so_obj.data.session;

  var date:Date = new Date();
  var max:int = 100;
  var first:String;
  var first_created:int=date.time;
  var cnt:int=0
  for (var p:String in session) {
    if (session[p].created < first_created) {
      first_created = session[p].created;  
      first = p;
    }
    if (++cnt == max) 
      delete session[first];
  }

  session[url] = new Object();
  session[url].created = date.time;
  session[url].info = info;

}
```